# g++ invokes private copy constructor instead of constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, g++

Here is the offending code. It compiles under Visual Studio 2010 but fails compilation under g++ 3.4.x and 4.1.x. I didn't have immediate access to a more recent g++ so couldn't check.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Color {
  enum Colors {
    red, blue, green, yellow
  };

  Color(Colors c) : col(c) {}

private:
  Colors col;
  Color(const Color& c);                                 // line 12
  Color& operator=(const Color& c);
};

std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& os, Color const&) { return os; }

int main()
{
  std::cout << Color(Color::red) << std::endl;  // line 20
}
```

The error on g++ is:

> tmp5.cpp:12: error: "Color(const Color&)" is private.
>   tmp5.cpp:20: error: within this context.

Comment: [Immediate access to a more recent g++](http://ideone.com/Jocdxn). But I don't think this is your real code anyway, given the mismatched use of namespace `Foo`.

Comment: Where is foo definition?

Comment: How does a compiler determine the most suited overload for a method? Does it ignore access modifier to locate the best suited match, which is the const & version?

Comment: Additionally, you are calling the Color constructor with a Colors parameter, and there is no such declared constructor.

Comment: @juanchopanza : no, it requires a constructor taking a Colors parameter.

Comment: @Samuel Yes, overload resolution ignores member access control.

Comment: @galinette Correct, I removed my comment.

Comment: Apologies for posting incorrect code. I have fixed the issues and removed namespace Foo references.

Comment: @juanchopanza : now it's here :)

Comment: FWIW, here's a fixed up version working on a recent GCC: http://ideone.com/37mso1

Comment: Are you sure this exact code does not compile since you apparently posted a modified version for not showing your real code?

Comment: @Samuel "Does it ignore access modifier to locate the best suited match, which is the const & version?" That's correct, access is checked after selecting the right name.